# Visual Studio 2019 RDLC already Installed but still missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, rdlc

I have already installed a RDLC report designer but still nothing shows when I'm adding a report. I know this topic already existed but nothing solve the problem. here's some reference what I already installed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use report designer correctly, I did these operations:

First, I installed Microsoft RDLC Report Designer which version is '15.3.1'.

[image]

Second, I choose Add New Item under Project option in tool.

[image]

Finally, we can find report choice under Visual C# Items or search for report in the search bar.

[image]

Currently It will be a good choice to download the latest version of report designer.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001

By the way, when you search in 'Add New Item', please select 'Visual C# Items' instead of other categories.

Comment: wow its in plain sight and yet i didn't see it. thank you for your answer super appreciate it.